# tableview reloadData click on the headerSection to expand the row

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I placed a timer to execute tableview reloadData every second, then
viewForHeaderInSection customizable an expandable headerView, I found that frequent clicks on the headerView expansion row will be confused, sometimes the expanded row will be under other sections, who can help me solve？

The Demo project can be find here: 
https://github.com/gisxie/tableview

Comment: In your sample there exists a racing condition. When reloading data at everything second, your delegate method -(void)selectedWithHeadView:(TrendHeadView *)headView{} may be initiated by user's tap. In this method, your tableview is reloadSections. If you remove the reloadSections. You can get your view every second with the right order. So that is the issue.

Comment: I know,but if I remove the reloadSections,I won't be able to expand the row.Is there a better way to satisfy my needs?

Comment: Redesign the priority. It takes time to think this kind of questions.

Comment: If your reload data task takes a lot of time, such as 1 s, You even don't need to reload your specific section again.  If its loading takes 0.05 s, you can divide your every second into 10 time spans. Only allow one or two spans to run your data load while allowing other time zones to respond to your user interaction. The key here is the data loading task should take as little as time, then you can divide your time to 50 per second and your user will not feel any delay.